How are Topic Space and Namespace topics are related in Azure
I am trying to use MQTT Broker feature of Azure Event Grid Namespace. I am able to send data to topic space successfully and these events are visible in  Namespace overview but not in topic which I am sending to. On the other hand it is always disconnecting if I try to send to Namepspace topic directly.
I have created a topic space and template as below
namespace/AzureEventGridTopicSpace which have a template as AzureEventGridTopicSpace/sampleTopic
Also, I have a topic in the same namespace as
namespace/ExampleTopic
Now If I send data to ExampleTopic the MQTT Connection is being disconnected with return code 7. But, when I send data to AzureEventGridTopicSpace/sampleTopic, I am able to send successfully but not reflecting in the Namespace Topic.
I wanted to know the relation and how can I send data to Namespace topic. If not this, how can I route the data from sampleTopic to any other custom topic?
Edited:
Attaching the namespace topic space configuration in which I could not see the destination topic. How can I set this?
Image

It seems that I need to enable the MQTT Routing in Namespace and select the Namespace topic to route all the data that I receive on Topic Space templates.
Thank you.
